# How to create category attribute of type int in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I am using Magento 2.3

I have created the Custom extension for category attribute "Popular category" and I have installed this extension successfully but the issue is I have set the default value as 0 but when I saw the attribute in admin it is already selected.

Here are the extension files:

> app/code/Custom/CategoryAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php


namespace Custom\CategoryAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'popular_category',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Popular Category',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'default' => 0,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> app/code/Custom/CategoryAttributes/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="include_in_menu" sortOrder="100" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Popular Category</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Attribute in admin:

[image]

As you can see attribute is already selected to "Yes" but I want it to be selected as "No" by default. So, how can I achieve this?

And also I am not able to use this attribute in the front end. So, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your InstallData.php file and it is working perfectly.

The issue is in your

> app/code/Custom/CategoryAttributes/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

you use "include_in_menu" as the name in field tag, use your custom attribute name "popular_category" instead of "include_in_menu".

Below is my code which I tried

> app/code/Mycompany/CategoryAttribute/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\CategoryAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();


    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'is_popular_category',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Popular Category',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
            'default' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 10,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'visible_on_front' => true,
        ]

    );

}
}
```

and change in tag "field" name

> app/code/Mycompany/CategoryAttribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
    <field name="is_popular_category" sortOrder="100" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Popular Category</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Instead of

```
'default' => 0
```

give as **null** and that select no by default

```
'default' => null
```

and input should be **boolean** not select

```
'input' => 'boolean'
```

instead of

```
'input' => 'select'
```

> NOTE : Remove your module from setup_module then run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and also delete your attribute from **eav_attribute** table.

Query to remove the module from **setup_module** table in M2

> DELETE from setup_module where module = 'Custom_CategoryAttributes';

and to delete it from **eav_attribute** table

> DELETE from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'popular_category';

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can I use this attribute in front end?

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya Use this in your category phtml $category->getPopularCategory()
// or
$category->getData('popular_category'); and $category is your category object

Comment: Can I use it in home page or in any other pages than category.phtml?

Comment: Yes anywhere you can but get category object followed by that get attribute